# How to change to string and remove &#39; from Django tempalates / context?

Tags: json, django, django-templates, django-views

I currently have a date that is formatted in unicode:

```
k = u'2015-02-01'
```

I tried to add this to a list and change it into a string:

```
date = []
date.append(str(k))
```

Then I want to pass this as a Django context to my template.

However, the date is showing up with the following:

```
&#39;2015-02-01&#39;
```

How do I just rid of $#39; and replace it with a double quote (")?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try to prevent string escape in template like this:

```
{{ variable|safe }}
```

In-view way:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.template import Context
data=mark_safe(data) 
inescapable = Context({'data': data}, autoescape=False)
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the escape string before I pass it as a context argument? I tried .strip() and that doesn't quite work.

Comment: Take look at this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211286/how-do-i-disable-djangos-autoescape-from-a-view

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774902/how-to-prevent-auto-escape-in-django-templates

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but other people might stumble upon this with the same problem

Try

```html
{% autoscape off %} {{ date }} {% endautoscape %}
```

It worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

When requesting graphs from google charts the data must be sent as a text array.  The csv file has to be pure text with no apostrophes.
however
code fragment
`data = repr(textData)`
returns data bounded by '  '
this is interpreted as "&#39" in html

The solution to this is to javascript split method
`var par = textData.split(""&#39") textArray = par[1]  // the part without '`
rest of code